# WIX: upgrade without removing old version

Tags: wix

I have installed version 2.4.0. And I have an major update:

```
<?define Version="2.4.1.0"?>
<Product Id="*" Name="SuperProduct" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="3.0.0.0" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes" />
</Upgrade>

<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="Cannot downgrade!" IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes" AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no" />
```

The major update should replace few dll files in my product (it contains only theese files). But the installer removes old version and installs new one. All old files except new files are removed. How can I install upgrade without removing old files (suppress RemoveExistingProducts). This is not an option to remove MajorUpgrade tag and receive 2 programs in Program Files (SuperProduct 2.4.0 and SuperProduct 2.4.1)
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Moved comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a patch instead of an upgrade. This is exactly what patches are for, replacing a few key files and leaving the rest of the install as-is. I haven't made a patch install yet but the steps should be in the wix tutorial or in Nick Ramirez's Wix 3.6 book. A minor upgrade may also work, I'm not 100% sure about the differences between the upgrade types as I always just implement a major upgrade

Comment: I need to make a major upgrade, not a patch

Comment: That's not how major upgrades work by definition. If you want all the old files still available you need to include them in the major upgrade installer as well. RemoveExistingProducts is what removes the entry from the Add Remove Programs list so suppressing this means you get two entries in the list. Why do you **need** a major upgrade? The purpose of Minor upgrades and patches is to replace a few files and update the version (minor upgrade) or leave the version the same (patch) while leaving all the other old files untouched.

Comment: You'll have to find your own resource for this, I would suggest Nick Ramirez' Wix 3.6 a developer's guide to Windows XML if you can find it. The majority of the content still applies to wix 3.10.2 (current release) and it has details about creating the 3 types of upgrades. There are probably other resources on the web and on stack exchange about making minor upgrades and patches.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for the book